# How to Speed Up My Time To First Byte on Magento Site?

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, performance

I am really bothered with my site speed. I have this magento site which has this site speed:
[image]

as you can see the total time is 2.15s and whole Site Speed is 2.71s([Full Waterfall View](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/cXq2sP/http://unlideals.com/)). All my resources are in good speed but my Time To First Byte is so Slow. How can I improve this? Any Solution to this?